# several cameras share data lines

Tags: arduino-uno, camera

There are plenty of projects that connect an OmniVision camera, such as ov7670 , to an Arduino.

A good example would be: 
https://www.scribd.com/document/356160003/Beginning-Arduino-Ov7670-Camera-Development

Now, let's say I want to connect 2 of those.

The problem with these cameras is that they require 17 IOs, which is a lot.

They are are:

- 1 power - cannot be shared
- 1 external clock (XCLK)
- 2 I2C lines (DATA, CLK)
- 8 data lines (D0:D7)
- 3 sync lines (PCLK, VSYNC, HREF)
- 2 control lines (RESET , PWD)

(Image attached below)

So, assuming I'm only powering 1 camera at a time, by giving each camera its own power IO, can all other IOs of both cameras be shared? at least some of them? (even if some intermediary simple HW is required)

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Though question. Do you know how the datalines behave, when the camera is unpowered? Are they high impendance or may there be a parasite current? I assume you want to process the images in the Arduino, thus using the data lines.

Comment: And are you sure, that you want to do this with an UNO? Even a little bit of image processing is a big task for an UNO

Comment: No Image processing, only relay. I want to later port it to some Atmel SAMD, I use Arduino for prototyping, and want the SAMD have the same solution, if possible.

Comment: I don't know about electric behavior, I was hoping to get suggestions about this.

Comment: You might be able to use the Power-down mode pin and set the control register to tri-state data output to allow connecting multiple devices to the same data bus.